# IBM integration Bus: cannot convert hex code : c280 to 437

Tags: utf-8, xml-parsing, ibm-integration-bus

Mq input node failing to parse xml due to unconvertable unicode characters with hexcode: c280 is received. source of incoming xml is some front end that supports all emoticons. help appreciated.

Comment: 0xC280 is the UTF-8 code for character [슀](https://www.utf8icons.com/character/49792/UTF-8-character), since CCSID 437 us a ASCII character set, I;n not sure what you would expect it to convert it to.  IBM MQ when a get with convert is issued would convert this to the default substitution character 0x1A which is a catch all for anything that can't be mapped to a character in the target CCSID.  0x1A I understand is not a valid XML character.

Comment: @JoshMc Hi JoshMc. Thank you for reply. the source file im receiving is in CCSID/encoding : 1208/273. but not sure broker is trying to use 437 as per user trace. my message flow is also using same 1208/273 combination in entire code both in Mqmd, properties and mqrfh2 headers. infact i tried using convert option on mqinput node to use 1208/273. But once xml is received, it is failing with parse error. can u please suggest a possible solutions deal with this .. appreciate your help.

Comment: im receiving the xml in mq input node and i write as a file to an aix file system directory using dfdl.

Comment: Please can you quote the error message in full. I think you are probably parsing the XML successfully but you are trying to write the output using code page 437. That will never work if your input contains characters that don't exist in 437.